# Responsive Wordpress menu not working - Hamburger not clickable

Tags: php, wordpress, header, navigation, responsive

so I'm making a website in wordpress, and I keep struggling with the main menu. The menu does some things stated in the media queries, but leaves out other things. The hamburger menu button is shown, but I can't click it. I don't know how I can fix it.

This is the code from header.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and 
everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-
files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package epw_theme
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('style.css'); ?>">


<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>


<div class="hero">
<div class="fullwidthbar">

<h1 id="headertext"><a id="headertext" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( 
'/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

</div>





<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation hdftbg" role="navigation">
        <div class="ham">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                            'menu_id' => 'myTopnav',
                            'menu_class' => 'topnav'
                        )); ?>
                        <div class="test">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" 
onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <script>
    function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                    x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                    x.className = "topnav";
            }
    }</script>
    </nav>


</div>


<div id="content" class="site-content">

</div>
```

And the css that goes with it:

```
/* Add a background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
background-color: #1d1f20;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
float: right;
display: block;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}



/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
color: #f77;

}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
display: none;
color: #000000 !important;
}

.icon {
display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links. Show the 
link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
.topnav a.icon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  }
.topnav {
    width: 100%;
}
}
.test {
  display: none;
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the 
user 
clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens 
(display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav.responsive {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block;
}

.test {
  display: block;
}

.topnav.responsive a.icon {
position: absolute;
right: 0 !important;
top: 0 !important;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.menu-item {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.superflex {
position: absolute !important;;
}
}

p.navigatie {
display: none;
}

ul {
float: right;
}

.ham {
background-color: #1D1F20;
width: 100%;
height: 3em;
}

#header{
margin-top: -55px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(http://st359450.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/epw/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/NorwayVang-2.jpg);
background-size: cover;
z-index: -100;
}

#header h3{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 300px;
}
#header h4{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 400px;
}

#arrowdown{
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 600px;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#headersec{
margin-top: -55px;
width: 100%;
height: 75%;
 background-image: url(http://st359450.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/epw/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/NorwayVang-small.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#tagline{
font-style: italic;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}

#lowerline{
font-style: italic;
font-size: 45px;
text-align: center;
color: #ccc;
}


html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
 }


body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.hero {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
 }

.hero h1  {
  margin-top: 0;
}


.hero .hdftbg {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 5% 100%);
}


 .hero {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}

.hero .hdftbg {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 5% 100%);
}

 .hdftbg{

 width: 50%;
    padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #1D1F20;
  float: right;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.fullwidthbar{
width: 100%;
background-color: #1D1F20;
height: 35px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}

  #headertext {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
  }

 #headerfield {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 300;
margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.menu-items{
margin-top: -20px;


}
```

The .hdftbg, .fullwidthbar and .hero are all used for the clip path, which is why I can't remove them. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your question really isn't specific enough.

Comment: @Difster As you can see I have added media queries etc. to make the top navigation responsive. This is the exact same code a friend of mine also used. It did work for her, not for me. On my page the menu button does not show up, and before, when I changed a few things in the code, and hit the button, no menu came down. I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Have you opened the console and looked for errors?

Comment: Do you not have a fiddle or a website or anything we can actually see this in action at as computing that much information in my brain cells at once is never going to happen I'm afraid.

Comment: I have, can't find any errors. @Difster

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Yes, the link: http://st359450.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/epw/